# Unable to send innerHTML using chrome.scripting.executeScript in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm developing a Chrome Extension that aims to capture the innerHTML of the current tab's page when a button is clicked in the extension popup and send it to a server. However, I'm encountering an issue with the code that uses chrome.scripting.executeScript, as it doesn't seem to send the innerHTML data as expected.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
     "name": "Web Scraper",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Extract innerHTML from web pages",
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
      
        "128": "logo.png"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "logo.png"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
      "http://localhost:8000/*"
    ]
  }
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Web Scraper</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="scrapeButton">Scrapping Page</button>
  <p id="jokeElement">Loading...</p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
document.getElementById('scrapeButton').addEventListener('click', () => {

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: chrome.tabs.getCurrent().id },
    function: scrapePage
  });
});

window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);

function windowLoaded() {
    alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
}

function scrapePage() {
  const innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
  fetch('http://localhost:8000/receive-data', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ innerHTML }),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const jokeElement = document.getElementById('jokeElement');
      jokeElement.innerHTML = "hello";
    console.log(data.message);
  });
}
```

The scrapePage function is supposed to capture the innerHTML and send it to a background script for further processing. However, it doesn't appear to be working as intended.

the backend code -

**app.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class DataItem(BaseModel):
    innerHTML: str

@app.post("/receive-data/")
async def receive_data(data: DataItem):
    print("Received Data:")
    print(data.innerHTML)
    return {"message": "Data received successfully"}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Do you get anything sent to the server?

Comment: No I'm not getting anything on the server. The issue is that I want the whole innerHTML of that tab when I click the click button on extension.. but seems like it's not working .

Comment: ```chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: chrome.tabs.getCurrent().id },
    function: scrapePage
  });
```
this part is not working

Comment: 1) getCurrent returns a Promise, not a tab. 2) It'll be null because the popup isn't a tab. 3) Use an async function and chrome.tabs.query as shown in [this example](/a/68543098). 4) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @IonFreeman in script.js - 
```
 chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: chrome.tabs.getCurrent().id },
    function: scrapePage
  });
 ```
this funciton is not working.. I want to get the innerHTML data , but as the function is not working I'm not getting any data.